# Android 11 : ANR Happening due to AudioPolicyService server died!. During VoIP call, while Audio routing from Bluetooth to Earpiece/Speaker

Tags: android, android-source, voip

beginning of crash

TimeCheck  TimeCheck timeout for IAudioPolicyService command 6

Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 2268 (TimeCheckThread), pid 841 (audioserver)

A  pid: 841, tid: 2268, name: TimeCheckThread  >>> /system/bin/audioserver <<<

signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------

Abort message: 'TimeCheck timeout for IAudioPolicyService command 6'
x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000008dc  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000006df5169530

MESSAGE_HANDLE_DISABLE_DELAYED: disabling:false

AudioFlinger server died!

AudioPolicyService server died!

Command failed for android_media_AudioSystem_error_callback: -32

Waiting for service 'media.audio_flinger' on '/dev/binder'...

TimeCheck timeout for IAudioPolicyService command 6
AudioPolicyService server died!
AudioFlinger server died!